# Unit Testing: should change class after click

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

When clicking on `<mat-expansion-panel>` (`Angular Material`) it should add a class `mat-expanded` but whenever I run the function the DOM is still the same when I log it, the class is not added.

**HTML**

```
<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="toggleCollapseRow('open')" (closed)="toggleCollapseRow('closed')">
...
```

**Function in compononent.ts**

```
public toggleCollapseRow(openOrClosed: string): void {
    if (openOrClosed === 'open') {
        this.expandCollapseIcon = 'ic_collapse_default';
    } else if (openOrClosed === 'closed') {
        this.expandCollapseIcon = 'ic_expand_default';
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
it('should expand on click', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const panel = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('mat-expansion-panel');
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'toggleCollapseRow').and.callThrough();
    panel.click();
    component.toggleCollapseRow('open');
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // this logs the same output with no class added
    console.log(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('mat-expansion-panel'));
    expect(spy);
    expect(component.toggleCollapseRow).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.expandCollapseIcon).toEqual('ic_collapse_default');
}));
```

This all succeeds but when I add the following, it fails because the DOM is still the same:

```
expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-expanded')).toBeTruthy()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the test tests how `toggleCollapseRow` works, it shouldn't involve a click. If it tests how template works, `component.toggleCollapseRow('open')` shouldn't be called directly. The expectations were successful just because of that.

As explained in [the guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#triggereventhandler), DOM events should be triggered with `DebugElement` `triggerEventHandler`, because `HTMLElement` `click` doesn't involve bindings.

It likely should be:

```
const panelDE = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatExpansionPanel));
const spy = spyOn(component, 'toggleCollapseRow').and.callThrough();
panelDE.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
tick();
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(component.toggleCollapseRow).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.expandCollapseIcon).toEqual('ic_collapse_default');
expect(panelDE.classes['mat-expanded']).toBeTruthy()
```

Comment: What's `By.directive(MatExpansionPanel)` ? I don't seem to have an import for that. Using your code, it still didn't add the class unfortunately

Comment: If you don't have imports, it will reasonably cause an error. Of course, it won't add class then. You should add imports for that. Use IDE auto-imports if it's capable of that. By is Angular helper, https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/By . MatExpansionPanel is component class that should be exported by Material.

Comment: Right, it imported the MatExpansionPanel now. Still it fails on all tests. The icon isn't equal, the function isn't called and the last one is falsy

Comment: I'd expect it to work. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem in action  - Plunker, Stackblitz, etc. Also, since you're not supposed to test Material units (that's a job for Angular team), you can also go more direct approach, something like `panelDE.componentInstance.opened.emit()` instead of `triggerEventHandler`. Another option is to provide dummy `<mat-expansion-panel>` component instead of real one, in order to eliminate unneeded moving parts.